# Exception caught by image resource service, The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load an image into a scroll, but every time it does not load the image due to error:

```
Exception caught by image resource service The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/jorge.png
```

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
```

```
1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:44)
```

```
2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:449:14)
...

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/jorge.png")

Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#dd41f(), name: "assets/images/jorge.png", scale: 1.0)
```

(2) Exception caught by image resource service

```
 Unable to load asset: assets/images/heitor.png
```

(3) Exception caught by image resource service

```
 Unable to load asset: assets/images/john.png

 I/chatty  ( 8763): uid=10206(com.festapp.flutter_app_fest) identical 5 lines
 E/AccessibilityBridge( 8763): VirtualView node must not be the root node.


 flutter clean was used, besides exchanging images

 final User currentUser = User(
  id: 0,
  name: 'Current User',
  imageUrl: 'assets/images/greg.png'
);
```

//usuários

```
final User Jorge = User(
  id: 1,
  name: 'Jorge',
   imageUrl: 'assets/images/jorge.png'
);

final User John= User(
   id: 2,
   name: 'John',
   imageUrl: 'assets/images/john.png'
); 

final User Heitor = User(
   id: 3,
   name: 'Heitor',
   imageUrl: 'assets/images/heitor.png'
```

);
    final User Gui = User(
       id: 4,
       name: 'Gui',
       imageUrl: 'assets/images/heitor.png'
    );

and images use in:

```
return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 35.0,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage(favorites[index].imageUrl),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 6.0,
                  ),
                  Text(favorites[index].name, style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

Exception caught by image resource service

The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:

```
Unable to load asset: assets/images/jorge.png
```

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
```

```
1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:44)
```

```
2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:449:14)
...
 Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/jorge.png")
 Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#dd41f(), name: "assets/images/jorge.png", scale: 1.0)
```

(2) Exception caught by image resource service

```
Unable to load asset: assets/images/heitor.png
```

(3) Exception caught by image resource service

```
Unable to load asset: assets/images/john.png
```

Answer (score 4):

i also faced the same issue,
the solution is to stop the main.dart -by clicking the red button given in taskbar
and then restart it.
sometime its not able to load the images when you add it as fresh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that these image files aren't in your project:

- `assets/images/jorge.png`
- `assets/images/john.png`
- `assets/images/heitor.png`

Make sure you are doing these things:

- Add the images in the folder `assets/images/`
- Specify the images in `pubspec.yaml`
- Execute `flutter packages get` / tap `Packages get` from
  `pubspec.yaml` / tap `Get dependencies` from any dart file.
- Use `Image.asset()` or `AssetImage()` to show them.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error, you should check your pubspec.yaml file, either the asset folder is indexed like below or not:

```
flutter:

[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:                  
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/images/  #index all files inside images folder
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- assets/images/elephant.jpg #index only elephant.jpg
```